# base64 decoding issue (special character?)

Tags: r, base64, ascii, mime-types, mime

I have extracted this from the body of an email:

```
txt <- "PHRhYmxlIGFsaWduPSJjZW50ZXIiIGNlbGxzcGFjaW5nPSIwIiBib3JkZXI9IjAiIGNlbGxwYWRkaW5nPSIwIiBzdHlsZT0icGFkZGluZy10b3A6IDEwcHg7IiB3aWR0aD0iNjEycHgiPgoJPHRyPgoJCTx0ZCB3aWR0aD0iNjEycHgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTM2cHgiIHN0eWxlPSJsaW5lLWhlaWdodDogMDtwYWRkaW5nOjA7Ij48aW1nIHNyYz0iaHR0cHM6Ly9kMjZraHJ2OHhkNW9hYS5jbG91ZGZyb250Lm5ldC9lZG0vYmdfbG9nb19kZWZhdWx0XzYxMngxMzYuZ2lmIiB3aWR0aD0iNjEycHgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTM2cHgiIC8-PC90ZD4KCTwvdHI-CQoJPHRyPgoJCTx0ZCB2YWxpZ249InRvcCIgd2lkdGg9IjYxMnB4IiBzdHlsZT0ibGluZS1oZWlnaHQ6IDA7cGFkZGlu"
```

(I have cut the message at 500 characters for confidentiality reasons)

I need to convert it to html.

```
txt = substr(txt,1,500)  
RCurl::base64Decode(txt = txt)
```

However this gives me only the first part of the message:

```
<table align=\"center\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" style=\"padding-top: 10px;\" width=\"612px\">\n\t<tr>\n\t\t<td width=\"612px\" height=\"136px\" style=\"line-height: 0;padding:0;\"><img src=\"https://d26khrv8xd5oaa.cloudfront.net/edm/bg_logo_default_612x136.gif\" width=\"612px\" height=\"136px\"
```

It seems that there is a special character that creates an issue but I can't find which one exactly. Is it a problem of ISO / UTF encoding?

Note: if I use the online tool https://www.base64decode.org/ with ISO-8859-1 I get more characters (although the decodes characters do not make sense for me)

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding-top: 10px;" width="612px">
<tr>
    <td width="612px" height="136px" style="line-height: 0;padding:0;"><img src="https://d26khrv8xd5oaa.cloudfront.net/edm/bg_logo_default_612x136.gif" width="612px" height="136px" /ÝOÝ ÇG#à ÇFBfÆvãÒ'F÷"vGFÒ#c'"7GÆSÒ&ÆæRÖVvC¢·FF
```

Comment: I get more character with `rawToChar(RCurl::base64Decode(txt = txt, mode = "raw"))`, but with an error.

Comment: @Pascal Same here, but the extra characters are weird (/\017\v\335\031\017\202\202O\v\335\034\200\220\240\223\307G#\340\240\220\223\307FB\af\026\306\226v\343\322'F\367\002"\av\226GF\203\322#c\023'\a\202"\a7G\226\306S\322&\306\226\346R\326\206V\226v\207C\242\003\003\267\006\026FF\226\346s\243\003\262 ($$$\361\321\205\211\261\224\) . hence I am wondering if there there is a way to specify the ISO of the characters?

Comment: I see `<table align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding-top: 10px;" width="612px">\n\t<tr>\n\t\t<td width="612px" height="136px" style="line-height: 0;padding:0;"><img src="https://d26khrv8xd5oaa.cloudfront.net/edm/bg_logo_default_612x136.gif" width="612px" height="136px"\0\x80\xbc</td>\n\t</\001\xd1\xc8\t\n\t<tr>\n\t\t<td valign="top" width="612px" style="line-height: 0;paddin`

Comment: @Pascal What does `getOption("encoding")` and `Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")` return on your machine?

Comment: Good question. Respectively `"native.enc"` and `"en_US.UTF-8"` (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: I changed to your settings but still get the same result `<table align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding-top: 10px;" width="612px">\n\t<tr>\n\t\t<td width="612px" height="136px" style="line-height: 0;padding:0;"><img src="https://d26khrv8xd5oaa.cloudfront.net/edm/bg_logo_default_612x136.gif" width="612px" height="136px" /\017\v\xdd\031\017\x82\x82O\v\xdd\034\x80\x90\xa0\x93\xc7G#\u0810\x93\xc7FB\af\026Ɩv\xe3\xd2'F\xf7\002"\av\x96GF\x83\xd2#c\023'\a\x82"\a7G\x96\xc6S\xd2&Ɩ\xe6RֆV\x96v\x87C\xa2\003\003\xb7\0[...]xad\x9dɽչ\x90\xf4\x89\xa1\xd1\xd1\xc1\xcc輽\x90\`

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the different base 64 decoding functions in R are not behaving the same way on my example:

*`RCurl::base64Decode(txt)` is only returning the first part of the text.
*`paste(rawToChar(base64enc::base64decode(txt), multiple = TRUE),collapse="")` is returning weird characters
*`gmailr:::base64url_decode_to_char` is the only one that works fine in my case